# Spritebuilder how can I change the animation ( CCB file ) of a CCNode programmatically?

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I'm trying to make a Spritebuilder iPhone game, and my main character _player is a CCNode whose child is a CCBFile which holds the character's idle animation.

I want to change this _player's CCBFile to another CCBFile called ForwardDash.ccbi which contains the 'attack' animation when the player touches the screen.

This is what I'm trying:

```
 //_player is a CCNode, its first child is the CCBFile with the idle animation.
 //animar is a pointer to the CCBFile with the ForwardDash animation

 CCSprite *wat = _player.children[0];
           CCNode *animar = [CCBReader load:@"ForwardDash"];
           [wat setSpriteFrame: (CCSpriteFrame*)animar];
```

It fails and gives me the error: 'Thread 1: signal SIGABRT'

Comment: that's because animar is a CCNode (or subclass) instance, not a CCSpriteFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setSpriteFrame is not the method you are looking. If you want to keep your current CCB setup you should be able to accomplish what you want by doing:

```
CCSprite *wat = _player.children[0];
[wat removeFromParent];
CCNode *animar = [CCBReader load:@"ForwardDash"];
[_player addChild:animar];
```

While this works, I would recommend you try taking advantage of different animation timelines in SpriteBuilder. You can add new timelines to a CCB file and then change animations programmatically without removing and adding a new node. You can read a bit more about using timelines [here](https://www.makeschool.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spritebuilder/sprite-animation-spritebuilder/). Once set up, you'll be able to start a new animation with:

```
CCSprite *wat = _player.children[0];
CCAnimationManager* animationManager = wat.animationManager;
[animationManager runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:@"ForwardDash"];
```